# How to get a line after after a certain character in PHP?

Tags: php

I use explode() but I can only get before or after keyword in the same line. But if I want a line after keyword For example

> Hello Google
>
> Good morning Facebook
>
> Good Afternoon Twitter

How to get "Good morning Facebook" by using "Google" as keyword for search ?

Line number is not the same in every searching but keyword is the same.

My condition is I can't get all example text as one string. content is in a file and all the file is one string. I have to search specific keyword then I need a whole line after the keyword line.

Comment: *I use explode() but I can only get before or after keyword in the same line* - why? Have you got all of this text in a single string?

Comment: Each sentence is not in same line as I know if I use keyword as "morning" with explode() I can get "Good" for index 0 and I can get "Facebook" for index 2

Comment: If you `explode` that string using **morning**, you'll get *Hello Google Good* in index 0 and *Facebook Good Afternoon Twitter* in index 1. [See?](https://3v4l.org/VBfTg). If these sentences are actually in different variables (or in an array/file/etc), you need to explain that in the question.

Comment: My condition is I can't get all example text as one string. content is in a file and all the file is one string. I have to search specific keyword then I need a whole line after the keyword line.

Comment: You keep saying you can't do things, but don't explain why. *Why* can't you read the whole file into a single string? That's exactly what `file_get_contents` does. And *if* you can't do that, you need to explain what you *can* do. Are you reading it into an array? Iterating over it line by line?

Answer (score 0):

Non regex solution:

Loop the lines of the array and when found "Google" continue the array position to next item.
Then if line is not empty and found is true break the loop and line will be the line you are trying to find.

```
$str = 'Hello Google

Good morning Facebook

Good Afternoon Twitter';

$arr = explode("\n", $str);

$found = false;
foreach($arr as $line){
    if(strpos($line, "Google")){
        $found = true;
        continue;
    }
    if($found && $line != "") Break;
}
Echo $line;
```

https://3v4l.org/ME6B7

Comment: My condition is I can't get all example text as one string. content is in a file and all the file is one string. I have to search specific keyword then I need a whole line after the keyword line.